# How to cache $http but also be able to delete in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

Here is the problem. I get Items with `$http.get(url, {cache: true})` and assign to `$scope.items`. That works fine. Then I delete item in the list. I send `$http` to delete and then splice item from `$scope.items.splice($index, 1)`. So item deleted from the list.

Now I do to another page of my app. And when I return I see all items including those I deleted.

```
UserApi.getCoachProfiles().success(function(data) {
    if(!data.error) {
        $scope.data.profiles = data.result;
    }
});

$scope.delete = function(id, index) {
    UserApi.deleteProfiles(id).success(function(data) {
        if(!data.error) {
            $scope.data.profiles.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Something like this.

I am using UI Router states.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `{cache: true}` option why not use a cache from the [**`$cacheFactory`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory). Assign a cache from a `$cacheFactory` instance, whenever you delete an item, simply remove all items in the cache instance and `$http` will simply invoke another http request when it is called.

Example, let's say you have an `ItemService` that has a `query()` and `remove()` method for fetching items and removing an item. Create a `$cacheFactory` instance to be assigned in each `$http.get()` request, and perform a `removeAll()` for that cache instance when deleting an item in the list.

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BdvB3JdAmiQzFNXfvUea?p=preview)

```
  .service('ItemsService', function($http, $cacheFactory) {

    var cache = $cacheFactory('items');

    this.query = function() {
      return $http.get('/items', {cache: cache});
    };

    this.remove = function(id) {
      return $http.delete('/items/' + id).then(function(result) {
        // removeAll() when DELETE request was successful
        cache.removeAll();
        return result;
      });
    };

  })

  .run(function(ItemsService) {

    console.log('get all items');
    ItemsService.query()

      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log('removing one item');
        return ItemsService.remove('e456j7h3g4534w65eh56gw456546g001');
      })

      .then(function() {
        console.log('get all items again');
        return ItemsService.query();
      })

      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      });

  });
```

Comment: Yes this is one option. But we discussed it in comments. If you have app where user interact a lot, then it will always invoke new requests. But on the other hand, I know that I deleted this item. I can only delete it from items list and that is it. imagine 100 users work with list add and remove items. And it can add 20x times more requests to the server when it is not needed. What I what is to load data on first load and from that point only work locally. Of course send delete and add requests.

Comment: Are the cached requested data, exclusive only for each user, or is it shared? If it is shared between users wherein other users can manipulate the data, then you might have some problems in syncing data when you're not sending GET requests to get the newly added data.

Answer (score -1):

When you use `{ cache: true }` in the `$http.get()` call, what Angular is doing is recording an entry into `$templateCache` keyed on the Url. The documentation on the Angular site for [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) is sparse, but the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/cacheFactory.js) shows a public `remove()` method.

Knowing this, inject $templateCache into whatever controller or directive your $scope.delete function is called. You need to remove the call to get all items from the cache with the same url you originally retrieved them from using `$templateCache

Comment: This will force to reload data from server. But I do not what that. Why should I reload list of items when I know that only this item was deleted. It is common sense just to delete this item in array. That is all. What do you think?

Comment: I understand that it will force the reload. The issue is that the $templateCache is really just storing the raw HTML output as sent by the server. You could do what you want by parsing the output of `$template.get(url)`, removing the appropriate HTML elements, and then `$template.put(url, updatedHtml)` to replace the template. That seems more difficult and error prone.

Comment: Additionally, if the call to get all the items hits the server to query a data source to retrieve a list of all current items you may not want to cache at all because you cannot control when other users are deleting items.

Comment: This is absolutely incorrect as described in the [AngularJS `$http` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage), $http's cache uses `$cacheFactory` not `$templateCache`.

Comment: In this case it is a user owned items. No one can delete it. But there will be cases like you say. If through all aplication I reload data after manipulation, that will dramatically hit server which I want to avoid. 

Anyway thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @ryeballar yes I know. But I did not pay attention because this is not the point. The name makes no difference. The point is how to avoid behavior I described.

Comment: After some time, it looks like my whole concept of architecting services was wrong. It is getting better now. Callbacks play huge role, but I am not get used to it after 15 years of PHP :))

Comment: @ryeballer, you are correct. When using `cache: true` the $http service will create its own cache with $cacheFactory. You can pass `cache: $templateCache` to $http so that you have access to it.